# PyGTK Glade File Manager

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I am trying to make a file manager in python that looks like GNOME default file manager (nautilus) Because I am developing a FilePane plugin for a python written text editor. I don't know if there is a widget to give me the same look of Nautilus. If not, what widgets can I use to get a nice looking file manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched GTK API and I found that GTK TreeView does what I want.